# XSLT to get parent of node with a particular value

Tags: xslt

What is the XSLT to get a parent node based on the value of the child?

My xml:

```
<cast>
  <character>
    <name>Bugs</name>
    <id>1</id>
  </character>
  <character>
    <name>Daffy</name>
    <id>2</id>
  </character>
```

I have tried this:

```
<xsl:template match="/cast/character/id">
    <xsl:if test="text()=1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../self" mode='copier'/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode='copier'>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

But this outputs the text of every node in the document.

EDIT: I have to output XML here, I'm planning to extend this to XML generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/*/character[id=1]"/>
```

**or, if the wanted node should just be copied with no further processing**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/*/character[id=1]"/>
```

Comment: Thx.  I read that XPath as 'of the children of the root, take that character element with a child whose id element has a text node with integer 1."  Yes?  Would this expression would break if an additional branch were interposed above the level with the id elements?

Comment: @chernevik: If a modification is made to the source XML document so that the `character` elements are no longer children of the top element, this XPath expression will not select any node and will need to be changed. However, it is better to change it again to a specific XPath expression than using `//character` -- because the `//` XPath pseudo-operator can be extremely slow (it typically causes a whole (sub) tree to be traversed).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're printing everything because the processor starts matching at the root and the only template you specify is for `id` elements, so things get copied by default.  Try this:

```
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <output method="text" />
    <template match="/">
        <apply-templates select="//id" />
    </template>
    <template match="id">
        <if test="text()='1'">
            <value-of select=".." />
        </if>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

Or if you just want the character name, you could replace the `select` attribute value in the `value-of` element with "`../name`".

Comment: This doesn't work for me, outputs nothing.  Also, I need to output xml.

Comment: Also tried replacing value-of with copy-of, and removing single quotes around the string 1.  No sale.

Comment: NEVER MIND.  It _does_ work, prior comments reflected a typo.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/cast/character">
     <xsl:if test="id=1">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not able to add a comment. Hence put it here